# Using font-awesome in ionic 2

Tags: icons, font-awesome, ionic2

How can i use **[fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)** with `ionic 2`, i've following [this tutorial](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/extend-ionic2-add-custom-fonts-icons-ionic-config-json/48589) but it's not working.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update in ionic 2 RC.0**

- Download the font-awesome library.
- Create "fonts" folder in src/assets and copy the fonts from the font-awesome/fonts folder
- Copy the scss folder and paste it under src/theme/scss
- Open the variables.scss file, and copy the below code

> @import "scss/font-awesome";  @font-face
>   { font-family: 'FontAwesome';    src:
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
>   src:
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}')
>   format('embedded-opentype'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}')
>   format('woff2'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}')
>   format('woff'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}')
>   format('truetype'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular')
>   format('svg');    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;  }

To include your icon in HTML

```
  <i primary class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-lg"></i>
```

**Ionic Beta**

Install fontAwesome from the npm library.

Modify the below changes to your gulpfile.ts.

- Include gulp task for adding icon css and fonts to your build

> ```
> gulp.task('myCss', function(){   
>      return gulp.src('path-to-your-font-lib/style.css')
>          .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/css'))    
> });  
> gulp.task('myFonts', function(){   
>     return gulp.src('path-to-your-font-lib/fonts/**/*.+(eot|svg|ttf|woff)')
>          .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/fonts'))    
> });
> ```

- Modify your gulp build and watch task as follows (Adding your font
  and css on watch and build)

> ```
> gulp.task('watch', ['clean'],  function(done){    
> //existing ionic2 code 
> } 
> gulp.task('build', ['clean','myCss','myFonts'], function(done){   
> //existing ionic2 code
> }
> ```

Include `@import "../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";` in **app.core.scss** file

To include your icon in HTML

```
  <i primary class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you

Comment: Works for me as well! Thank you. Just be careful, you might need replace ./font-awesome/font-awesome"; with ./[YOUR_FONT_AWESOME_SCSS_FOLDER]/font-awesome";

Comment: I prefer this method as if the CopyScripts change in the core then it won't affect my custom CopyScript

Answer (score 24):

**font-awesome ionic 2 integration only with configuration files.**

1. Download font-awesome via npm (`npm install font-awesome --save`)
2. In the file package.json from your project add this:

   ```
   "config": {
       "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
       "ionic_source_map": "source-map",
       "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js",
       "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
   }
   ```
3. On the root folder of your project create config folder and copy the files `copy.config.js` and `sass.config.js` (this files are located in `(..\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config)`
4. Modify the copied files. In sass.config.js add the reference to font-awesome,
   at the end verify that you have something like this

   includePaths: [
       'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
       'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
       'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',
       'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
   ],

The most important part here is the last line.

in `copy.config` add this:

```
copyFontAwesome:{
    src: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/',
    dest: '{{WWW}}/fonts/'
}
```

The most important part here is dest  `'{{WWW}}/fonts/'` and not `{{WWW}}/assets/fonts/'`, it because `font-awesome.css` search fonts in `"www/fonts"` file.

5. And finally add  `@import "font-awesome";` in `variables.css (src\theme folder)`

After perform all this steps you can use font-awesome in your ionic 2 project.

```
<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#14afef; font-size: small"></i>
```

It's all

Comment: Excellent! Just to add that I had to add to copy.config this:

  copyFonts2: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/fonts'
  },

Comment: Perfect. Working solution for ionic 2. Also, think about restarting your ionic server (ionic serve) after applying this solution.

Comment: I get this error

`File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome. Parent style sheet:`

Answer (score 8):

Similar Approach as @Edward suggested, but a bit cleaner way to do this would be

1) `npm install font-awesome --save`

2) In package.json, add

`"ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js",
 "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js",`

3) Create the below files at root level of your project and add following content.

In the file: `./config/copy.config.js`
Add

```
const copyConfig = require('../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/copy.config');
copyConfig.copyFonts.src.push('{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*');
```

In the file: `./config/sass.config.js`
Add

```
const sassConfig = require('../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/sass.config');

sassConfig.includePaths.push('node_modules/font-awesome/scss');
```

4) In `./src/theme/variables.scss`

```
$fa-font-path: "../assets/fonts";
@import 'font-awesome';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is still a lot of confusion on what is a best practice when it comes to adding FontAwesome to an ionic2 app. I wrote a tutorial about it to mitigate some of that confusion. I hope this helps anybody else out there looking for this info

http://luiscabrera.site/tech/2017/01/09/fontawesome-in-ionic2.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of the answers above but they were either too complicated or had a limitation when the core of Ionic2 was upgraded so here is my solution:

It requires manually upgrading of FA when a new version comes out but I don't need to upgrade often as I only use a few select icons.

Ignore the SASS files and copy the contents of \node_modules\font-awesome\fonts to \src\assets\fonts. Also copy \node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.min.css to the same place.

Reference the csss in your index.html file like this:

```
  <!--Custom Fonts-->
  <link href="assets/fonts/comfortaa/comfortaa.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/fonts/gloriahallelujah/gloriahallelujah.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then to use it, put this into the page's scss:

```
  .logo-text {
    font-family: 'comfortaa-bold';
  }
```

and this in the html:

```
<h4 class="white-text slogan-text">Come bien a la mitad de precio</h4>
```

And that should be it...

Comment: can u show an example of how to use it in html ? thanx

Answer (score 1):

### Update for Ionic 2, Ionic 3+: just one step:

Add font-awesome link to your `index.html`

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```