# How to remove default assets from ionic 2 build?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am learning Ionic 2; writing code in Visual Studio code. I created project using following command:

```
> ionic start --v2 MyFirstIonic blank
```

And then

```
> cd MyFirstIonic
> ionic platform add android
```

When I build and run, `> ionic run android`, ionic creates `assets` folder in `www` directory and copies font files for Ionicons, Roboto, and Noto-sans, which are added in apk during build process. I'd like to exclude Ionicons, Roboto, and Noto-Sans from final build, and use FontAwesome files instead. How will I be able to achieve this?

[image: Ionic's www folder after build]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122669/using-font-awesome-in-ionic-2 also assets are copied from `src/assets` to `www/assets` during serve,build or run

Comment: @suraj, I removed fonts from `src/assets` but still they were copied to `www/assets` during build. Thanks for the link. I am looking at that.

Comment: hmm.. I found [this](https://chriztalk.com/ionic-2-font-awesome/). According to it you have to edit [copy.config.js](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/copy.config.js) in your app scripts. But those changes would not be there if you refresh node modules

Comment: `copyFonts` copies your ionicon font resources. But I am not certain of a permanent fix only these hacky solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40934389/4826457

Comment: @suraj, thanks a lot man. I was searching 'how to remove assets'.

Comment: That answer worked?

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Just read the blogs. Trying.

Comment: @suraj, it worked. `copy.config.js` can be overridden at project level as well.I used font-awesome's sass files instead of adding `<link />` tag in `index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit your `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/copy.config.js`.
Sample file [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/copy.config.js).

Remove `copyFonts` entry :

```
copyFonts: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*', '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
  },
```

from the file. This copies the ionicon fonts to your `www` folder.
Also remove the assets you do not need from `src/assets` folder.
You can edit `copy.config.js` file to add any other assets into the build process.
Refer answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122669/using-font-awesome-in-ionic-2).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you delete the unnecessary files from:

`[project]/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/`

(Keep the `ionicons.*` files.)

You'll still have to do that every time you update ionic-angular but it's easier and less error prone than keeping track of changes to the app-scripts bundle.

Additionally, comment out the `roboto` and `noto-sans` imports in:

`[project]/src/theme/variables.scss`

--

If you still want to update the script then the right way to do that is to copy the file locally as `[project]/src/webpack.config.js` and add the following entry to your `package.json`:

`"config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
  }`

--

Hope that helps!