# Ionic 2 : Add a icons font to an Ionic 2 project

Tags: css, angular, fonts, ionic2

I want to add a specific icons font to my project Ionic 2. I just have a folder with my font but I don't know how to integrate it to the project.

I try to add webfont medical icons : 
https://samcome.github.io/webfont-medical-icons/

I tried to add it in my www/assets/fonts folder but I don't know witch file I have to update to use this fonts ?

**UPDATE**

I already had font awesome to my project. I tried to follow the same process :

I past the 4 fonts file in my www/assets/fonts folder.

I past a file "wfmi-style.min.css" in my www/assets/cass folder.

Finaly I write this in my src/index.html file :

```
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/wfmi-style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I have this error :

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8100/assets/fonts/webfont-medical-icons.ttf
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
http://localhost:8100/assets/fonts/webfont-medical-icons.woff
```

There is the code at the begining of my wfmi-style.min.css :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'webfont-medical-icons';
  src:url('../fonts/webfont-medical-icons.eot');
  src:url('../fonts/webfont-medical-icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/webfont-medical-icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/webfont-medical-icons.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/webfont-medical-icons.svg#webfont-medical-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for [Using font-awesome in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122669/using-font-awesome-in-ionic-2)

- Download the font-awesome library.
- Create "fonts" folder in src/assets and copy the fonts from the font-awesome/fonts folder
- Copy the scss folder and paste it under src/theme/scss
- Open the variables.scss file, and copy the below code

  @import "scss/font-awesome"; @font-face { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; src: url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
  url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
  url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
  url('../assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }

To include your icon in HTML

```
<i primary class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-lg"></i>
```

> for more follow the link
>   .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ion-icon class="fa fa-iconname"></ion-icon>` after fontawesome included.