# cannot set tab icon as font awesome icon

Tags: font-awesome, ionic3

The title is self explanatory. I have I installed Font Awesome icons on my ionic app and I can set icons anywhere I want but in tabs by doing something this:

```
<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

This is the code in my tabs and as you can see it has icons set already

```
<ion-tabs >
     <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabTitle="Film" tabIcon="film"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab2" tabTitle="People" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

but I would like to icons from Font Awesome instead which uses the previous tag I showed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you set up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122669/using-font-awesome-in-ionic-2 this?

Comment: yes I did. I can use them anywhere else except for tabs...

Comment: I found https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/ by google search.